# How to do the vector of sets in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdset

I can do a simple array of sets:
`set < char > * words = new set < char > [10]`
How I can do a vector of sets? 
This results in a compiler error:
`vector < set< char >> v` .
Thank you for answers!

Comment: Repeating the title in the question is not recommended and it is a poorly ask question. Add details, code you have tried, examples you have seen, what you are trying to accomplish etc.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do and what you mean by `dynamic array of sets`.

Comment: `vector<set<type> > arrSets;` This will create a dynamic array (`vector`) of sets. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Naveen: He'd probably want vector< shared_ptr< set< T > > > to avoid copying sets around needlessly.

Comment: (They did the sets) They did the vec-tor of sets! (They did the sets) It was pure programming sex!

Comment: `vector < set< char >> v` doesn't work because the compiler treats the `>>` as the right shift operator. Put a space between the two `>` like so: `vector < set< char > > v`.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that he's wondering why the `>>` is causing an error? I fixed the wording a bit. Seems like a legitimate question to me. Voting to re-open.

Comment: … also because OP added the example code shortly *after* it was closed.

Answer (score 8):

If `vector < set< char >> v` is exactly what you've got there (I hope you cut and pasted), you've run into one of the annoying little features of C++.

Those `>>` look to you like two closing angle brackets for two templates.  They look like a right shift operator to the compiler.  Change them to `> >` with a space in between.

Fortunately, this is being addressed in the C++ standard that should be ratified this year.  Unfortunately, you aren't working with a C++11-compliant compiler just now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of '>>' try '> >'... like so:

```
vector<set<char> > testVect;
```