# Vector of Sets in C++

Tags: c++, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do the vector of sets in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599642/how-to-do-the-vector-of-sets-in-c)

I want to have a set for the different levels that are in my code. A set at each level will be holding integer values. The number of these sets should be dynamic depending on the number of levels required ( which is given as input ).

For this, I wanted to have a dynamic set structure. How can I achieve this? Can I go for a vector with as many pointers to the sets as required? How do I achieve this? Is there any other method.

Can somebody give me a snippet for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector<set<int> > my_sets;
```

---

Adding an element to i-th set:

```
int number;
//...
my_sets[i].insert(number);
```

---

Searching an element in i-th set:

```
if(my_sets[i].find(number) != my_sets[i].end())
{
      // Number found
}
```

---

Iterate over i-th set:

```
for(set<int> :: iterator it = my_sets[i].begin(); it != my_sets[i].end();++it)
{
   // do something with integer value *it
}
```

---

Add a new set:

```
set<int> temp;
temp.insert(a);temp.insert(b);//...
my_sets.push_back(temp);
```

---

Erase i-th set:

```
my_sets.erase(my_sets.begin() + i );
```

Answer (score 2):

A vector of sets is simply `std::vector<std::set<type>>`. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: How do i access each set from the vector??